# How to assign ids for textboxes added using loop in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am arranging a dynamic table of textboxes using a loop. 
Please review the following code segment in view -

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Names) { %>
<% =Html.TextBoxFor(item.Name)%>
<% } %>
```

The problem here is that i want their unique ids to be generated so that i could access each textbox using JS.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards
Irfan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
<div class="editor-field">
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Names.Count; i++) { %>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Names[i].Name) %>
<% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, but will it generate unique ids for each textbox?

Comment: Yes, the ids will look like this: `Names_0_Name`, `Names_1_Name`, `Names_2_Name` and so on. And it will automatically bind back to your collection, when posting the form.